# using jquery to list all li after element loads

Tags: jquery, closest

```
<div id="preen_me" class="twitter_list"></div>
```

I have a jquery plugin which fills this div with a list of twitter post (ul and li's).

I want to get the list (it's content by order). on mouseup(or click) The problem that jquery doesn't seem to find that list because it is loaded after the page loads(i think)

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#preen_me").click(function () {
          alert($(this).find('ul').attr('class'));
          alert($(this).closest('li').attr('class'));
       }); 
});
```

but I get an undefined value. (they both have classes attributes, in case you are wondering)

Comment: When are ul and li elements added to the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find()` method for `li` as well.. Method [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes **up** thru the DOM, which is not what you want I guess.

```
alert($(this).find('li').attr('class'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvbW7/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead use the live function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#preen_me").live('click', function () {
          alert($(this).find('ul').attr('class'));
          alert($(this).find('li').attr('class'));
       }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#preen_me").click(function () {
      alert($(this).find('ul li').attr('class'));          
   }); 
})
```